# Can't launch anything with "./ <something.run> in terminal

Tags: command-line

Whenever I try to launch something with `./` after installing it, I get a message saying:

```
bash: ./: Is a directory
```

[image]

Am I suppoed to delete the `./` directory, because I can't find where it is.

Comment: why are You adding a space after "./" ? `./qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.7.0.run`, remember to set chmod to the file if the premissions are not set. `chmod +x qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.7.0.run`

Comment: There should not be <space> after the <./>, type the line complete without spaces eg ./runme.run

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of terminal text, paste the text directly into your question instead. https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8713/why-do-people-post-screenshots-of-their-terminals

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There should not be any space between "./" and "qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.7.0.run". You should do

```
./qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.7.0.run
```